# Unable to compile libplot example program from plotutils documentation

Tags: c, plot, png

I'm trying to compile example code that I found in the plotutils documentation. I added the appropriate search path for the plot.h header file and linked the binary to every object file that gets created when you make install plotutils 2.6. I'm on OS X 10.10.3 with Xcode 6.3.2 and I'm a novice when it comes to C programming or using Xcode.

The example code I'm trying to compile is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <plot.h>
#define MAXORDER 12
void draw_c_curve (plPlotter *plotter, double dx, double dy, int order)
{
    if (order >= MAXORDER)
    /* continue path along (dx, dy) */
        pl_fcontrel_r (plotter, dx, dy);
    else
    {
        draw_c_curve (plotter,
                      0.5 * (dx - dy), 0.5 * (dx + dy), order + 1);
        draw_c_curve (plotter,
                      0.5 * (dx + dy), 0.5 * (dy - dx), order + 1);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    plPlotter *plotter;
    plPlotterParams *plotter_params;
    /* set a Plotter parameter */
    plotter_params = pl_newplparams ();
    pl_setplparam (plotter_params, "PAGESIZE", "letter");
    /* create a Postscript Plotter that writes to standard output */
    if ((plotter = pl_newpl_r ("ps", stdin, stdout, stderr,
                               plotter_params)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn’t create Plotter\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pl_openpl_r (plotter) < 0) /* open Plotter */
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn’t open Plotter\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pl_fspace_r (plotter, 0.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 1000.0); /* set coor system */
    pl_flinewidth_r (plotter, 0.25); /* set line thickness */
    pl_pencolorname_r (plotter, "red"); /* use red pen */
    pl_erase_r (plotter); /* erase graphics display */
    pl_fmove_r (plotter, 600.0, 300.0); /* position the graphics cursor */
    draw_c_curve (plotter, 0.0, 400.0, 0);
    if (pl_closepl_r (plotter) < 0) /* close Plotter */
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn’t close Plotter\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pl_deletepl_r (plotter) < 0) /* delete Plotter */
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn’t delete Plotter\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The 2 issues Xcode identifies are:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__pl_z_maybe_output_image", referenced from:
      __maybe_output_image in b_defplot.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

b_defplot.o and other object files were generated when I tried installing plotutils 2.6 by first downloading it, and doing ./configure, make, and make install.

My ultimate goal is to use the libplot package in a program I'm writing that requires a few plots to be generated, and I want my program binary file to be self-contained (i.e. if I execute my program binary on any other computer without plotutils installed, it should still work). This is why I'm linking my binary with every object file that gets created in the libplot folder when I install plotutils as described above.

Any help with the error I'm getting or enlightening me on something I'm doing terribly wrong keeping in mind what my end goal is, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the second issue? This is "only" **one** linker error. And what does this have to do with Xcode?

Comment: Xcode seems to show this as 2 issues, the first being: `"__pl_z_maybe_output_image", referenced from:` and the second being: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. I just mentioned that I was using Xcode and I'm not an expert with the software so I may well be doing something incorrectly in it or misunderstanding the issues it indicates. Although, in this case, I suspect Xcode has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: in which case, Xcode is wrong, because this is really just one error.  The function in question is in [z_write.c](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/plotutils/2.6/z__write_8c.html#a9393f30f18882fc105b294ba8aef6c93), make sure that you are linking the `z_write.o` object file as well.

Comment: That was very helpful. However, when I installed plotutils, z_write.o was not generated. I do recall the install process had 2 errors related to z_write but I kind of hoped those errors would be irrelevant to my use of the libplot library. I apologize for not providing this information earlier. Do you have any idea why z_write.o was not generated or would you like me to try installing plotutils again and reporting the error here?

Comment: It would definitely be helpful if you posted the actual errors you encountered when trying to compile that file.

Comment: I don't know how you figured out the error was in z_write.c. But thanks anyway. So I downloaded plotutils 2.6 again, executed ./configure followed by make. I got two errors at this stage (before I even try make install). The first is: `z_write.c:167:22: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct png_struct_def'
  if (setjmp (png_ptr->jmpbuf))
/usr/local/include/png.h:584:16: note: forward declaration of
      'struct png_struct_def'
typedef struct png_struct_def png_struct;`

Comment: While the second is: `z_write.c:447:19: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct png_struct_def'
  longjmp (png_ptr->jmpbuf, 1);
/usr/local/include/png.h:584:16: note: forward declaration of
      'struct png_struct_def'
typedef struct png_struct_def png_struct;`

Comment: "I don't know how you figured out the error was in z_write.c" – Google. I googled the function name. And it seems you need to install libpng.

Comment: Thanks. I just installed libpng 1.6.17 (no issues) and tried re-installing plotutils 2.6 to no avail. The same errors occur and z_write.o is not generated. I'm piping commands to gnuplot instead as an alternative to plotting while I try to figure out how to get plotutils to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile the libplot example program successfully by following these steps:

1. Install plotutils via Homebrew using: `brew install plotutils`
2. Locate (within /usr/local/ or wherever your Homebrew installation resides) and link `libplot.2.2.4.dylib`to the C program you are trying to build (in this case, the C program is the one provided in the question).
3. Also make sure you include the `plot.h` header file in your header search path.

By following these steps, I was able to compile the above code (with the modifications shown below) cleanly and was able to export the png shown below. Homebrew seems to have saved me the trouble of building plotutils on my own.
[image: Test.png: Output of libplot example program]

I replaced `if ((plotter = pl_newpl_r ("ps", stdin, stdout, stderr, plotter_params)) == NULL)` with `if ((plotter = pl_newpl_r ("png", stdin, fp, stderr, plotter_params)) == NULL)` where `fp` is defined as follows:

`FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("/Users/username/path/Test.png", "w");
 // rest of example code shown above
 fclose(fp);`

Comment: Can you provide command line example of how you did the linking please